# No property 'component' error after creating new project with vue-cli

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

[This part of the documentation of Vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html#component-names) says that it should be possible to call a function `component` on the object returned by `createApp`.

I created a project using [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) with `vue create myApp`.
I selected Vue3 and added typescript to the project.

The generated project contains a file named `main.ts` where `createApp` is used.
I tried to use the `component` method as indicated in the doc and got the following error.

```
ERROR in src/main.ts:6:5
TS2339: Property 'component' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, {}>>'.
```

```
// main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App).mount('#app')

app.component("er", {})
```

Is there more setup to do in order to use all feature of Vue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createApp(App)` and `createApp(App).mount('#app')` are different object. The former is Vue instance, the latter is component instance.

It should be:

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.component("er", {})

const vm = app.mount('#app')
```